# What is the importance of Castelnuovo-Mumford regularity

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

For some reasons, I have to study the Castelnuovo-Mumford regularity.

There are some papers on this regularity, which can be found here : [Castelnuovo-Mumford Regularity](http://arxiv.org/find/all/1/OR+au%3aCastelnuovo_Mumford+all%3a+AND+EXACT+Castelnuovo_Mumford+regularity/0/1/0/all/0/1)

My question is: What is the importance of this regularity? What information will we know if we know about the Castelnuovo-Mumford regularity?

Comment: Well, it helps you prove some things about Hilbert schemes, which seems interesting enough. You might want to look at Mumford's _Curves on an Algebraic Surface_.

Comment: Have you seen http://mathoverflow.net/questions/80/what-is-interesting-useful-about-castelnuovo-mumford-regularity ?

Comment: @Quiaochu Yuan : Thanks for pointing it out.